# Bulk Upsert using DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs

Is it possible to do bulk upsert of items in DynamoDB similar to how MongoDB bulk write can do this?

I have this function in MongoDB looking to do something similar in DynamoDB:

```
async bulkSync(
    model: any | null,
    context: any[],
    filterKeys: Array<string> = ['_id'],
): Promise<any> {
    let operations = []; // Initialize the bulk operations array
    let i = 1;
    for (const record of context) {
        const filter: any = {};
        for (const key of filterKeys) {
            const path = key.split('.');
            const value = R.path(path, record);
            filter[key] = value;
        }
        operations.push({
            updateOne: {
                filter: filter,
                update: {
                $set: record,
                    $setOnInsert: {
                        created_at: record.updated_at,
                    },
                },
                upsert: true, // example update operation,
                setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
            },
        });
        if (operations.length % 500 === 0 || i === context.length) {
            await model.collection.bulkWrite(operations, {
                ordered: true,
                w: 1,
            });
            operations = [];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use [BatchWrite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html). In this case, DynamoDB will essentially handle concurrency for you, running multiple individual write requests in parallel. There is some overhead here in handling any failed requests.
2. Use the [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) request, and use node worker_threads module to implement concurrency on the client side.